# Why might an enum bit mask be checked with an extra comparison?

Tags: c, syntax

I've come across this a few times recently:

```
if ((flags & PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY) == PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY)
   ...
```

What's the reason for the extra comparison? Why not this?

```
if (flags & PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY)
   ...
```

My guess is that it's a leftover habit to silence warnings from the days of yore when compilers were more strict.

Comment: "when compilers were more strict" where do you get such idea from? Merely the reverse is true, the C language and compilers with it get more stricter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also the possibility that in the mask there is more than one bit set. In that case, the two comparisons have different semantics.

Comment: Yep, occurred to me seconds after I posted the question. Thanks.

Comment: To be precise, it is true iff all of the bits in `PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY` are set in `flags`. A slightly more efficient way to do this is `if ((~flags & PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY) == 0)` ... which I bury in an `ALL_BITS_SET` macro in my standard header file, which makes the code more readable/understandable as well.

Comment: @JimBalter definitely agree to being faster, at the cost of being less readable in my opinion. One has to do some extra mental translation to understand what it is doing.

Comment: @fayyazkl Wrong, it is more readable because I bury it in a macro with a meaningful name. Very few programmers (myself being one) readily grasp what `if ((x & y) == y)` does, so that isn't understandable at all.

Comment: @JimBalter Agree to the part of more readable macro name without showing implementation. Perhaps it is a difference of personal traits or what being used to of. I feel like naturally reading the above if (x&y == y) in a go. But have to put significant effort with the one with ~ and comparison with 0. I wonder if this is common with other people. Just my opinion

Comment: @fayyazkl `if (x&y == y)` is a sure-fire bug due to C operator precedence ... so much for your ability to naturally read C code. Also, I think you misread my comment ... I said I **am** one of those who readily grasps `if ((x & y) == y)` ... but I'm one of the *few*. I *also* readily grasp `if (!(~x & y))` ... but then, I've programmed in C for 35 years.

Comment: I was going to write only if (then for clarity added x and y). I guess i should have second thought about others being nit picky. I guess a comment or semi colon should have followed too since if alone makes little sense.

Comment: So probably i am the one who feels if (!(~x&y)).. takes longer to read (at least for me) so i just prefer writing the other unless efficiency in this is absolutely necessary. And i barely have 8 years or so with c. So it adds to my knowledge of habits and preferences of fellow programmers. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, the condition is true iff all of the bits in `PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY` are set in `flags`. A slightly more efficient way (on some architectures) to do this is `if ((~flags & PERFORM_DELETION_CONCURRENTLY) == 0)` ... which I bury in an `ALL_BITS_SET` macro in my standard header file, which makes the code more readable/understandable as well.